# I want to call PayPal MassPay API in JSON format

Tags: json, rest, api, paypal, masspay

https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp - this is for nvp.  How to invoke for JSON?
are the input parameters the same?  what are the response parameters?  I want to call this API from a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The Mass Pay API only supports SOAP/XML and NVP (name value pairs).

[developer guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayUsingAPI/)

However, there are many options you could use to convert from XML to JSON.

Like this one for instance: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js